# Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format

Tags: java, internationalization, locale

I have a question about formatting the Rupee currency (Indian Rupee - INR).

Typically a value like `450500` is formatted and shown as `450,500`. In India, the same value is displayed as `4,50,500`

For example, numbers here are represented as:

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000
```

Refer [Indian Numbering System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

The separators are after two digits, except for the last set, which is in thousands.

I've searched on the internet and people have asked to use the locale `en_GB` or pattern `#,##,##,##,##0.00`

I tried this on JSTL by using the following tag:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" type="currency" 
  pattern="#,##,##,##,###.00"/>
```

But this does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544454/get-the-currency-format-for-a-country-that-does-not-have-a-locale-constant  here you can find the answer

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Unfortunately on standard Java SE [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) doesn't support variable-width groups. So it won't ever format the values exactly as you want to:

> If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and the end of the integer is the one that is used. So `"#,##,###,####" == "######,####" == "##,####,####"`.

Most number formatting mechanisms in Java are based on that class and therefore inherit this flaw.

ICU4J (the Java version of the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/)) provides a [`NumberFormat`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/NumberFormat.html) class that **does** support this formatting:

```
Format format = com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("100000000")));
```

This code will produce this output:

```
Rs 10,00,00,000.00
```

Note: the `com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat` class does **not** extend the [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class (because it already extends an ICU-internal base class), it **does** however extend the [`java.text.Format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) class, which has the [`format(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Note that the [**Android version** of `java.text.DecimalFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat) class is implemented using ICU under the hood and **does** support the feature in the same way that the ICU class itself does (even though the summary incorrectly mentions that it's *not* supported).

Comment: I wonder, how many times has it been asked on good old forums.sun.com? Almost daily, isn't it? ;)

Comment: I wanted to use it my Android App, but what is worrying me is that Jar file size is 9MB.  My app currently is of size 2.5 MB, so adding 9MB to it seems like overkill

Comment: try using new DecimalFormat("₹ ##,##,##1");

Comment: @WandMaker For Android DecimalFormat seems to work. Look at Kiran's answer below.

Comment: Solution given by @CleanX is better. Uses the inbuild Java libraries

Comment: @Funkyidol: re-read the question. The answer you mention doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It does. I used the solution provided by CleanX and it worked perfectly for me. I did not had to include a new library to my Android app

Comment: How to remove rupees symbol

Comment: @MustafaShaikh: please ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I have searched for above in golang 
I got this library https://github.com/punithck/indianmoney

Comment: how to remove trailing "00"?

Comment: @PradipVadher: if you have a separate question, please post that as a question, not as a comment on a 9 year old answer.

Answer (score 31):

With Android, this worked for me:

```
new DecimalFormat("##,##,##0").format(amount);
```

**450500 gets formatted as 4,50,500**

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html - DecimalFormat supports two grouping sizes - the primary grouping size, and one used for all others.

Comment: It gives me "450,501" which is not the right answer!

Comment: Surprisingly it's working in android and not in Java 8. Don't know why. Isn't it Java :D

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes it works in Android. Tried this ##,##,###.##

Comment: I have searched for above in golang I got this library github.com/punithck/indianmoney

Answer (score 17):

here is simple thing u can do ,

```
 float amount = 100000;

 NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));

 String moneyString = formatter.format(amount);

 System.out.println(moneyString);
```

The output will be Rs.100,000.00.

Comment: But this is not what OP wants. He wants 1,00,000

Comment: The code snippet above does not yet format the currency in Indian format of separation of every 2 digits by a comma and the last 3 digits before the decimal place.

Answer (score 7):

I also got myself in same problem.
I was working with `DecimalFormat`.

I have no knowledge of `JSTL` but you can figure out something by my solution.

As, grouping size remains constant in `DecimalFormat`. I separated both parts, formatted them with different patterns and concat both. Here is the code.

```
public static String format(double value) {
    if(value < 1000) {
        return format("###", value);
    } else {
        double hundreds = value % 1000;
        int other = (int) (value / 1000);
        return format(",##", other) + ',' + format("000", hundreds);
    }
}

private static String format(String pattern, Object value) {
    return new DecimalFormat(pattern).format(value);
}
```

It will provide format like Indian Numbering System.

If you want decimal points, just add `".##"` in both conditions.

`"###"` to `"###.##"` and `"000"` to `"000.##"`.

Comment: This code has a huge bug. If you input 1999.95, it'll format it as 1,1000

Answer (score 7):

```
public String getIndianCurrencyFormat(String amount) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char amountArray[] = amount.toCharArray();
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    for (int i = amountArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (a < 3) {
            stringBuilder.append(amountArray[i]);
            a++;
        } else if (b < 2) {
            if (b == 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(",");
                stringBuilder.append(amountArray[i]);
                b++;
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(amountArray[i]);
                b = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
}
```

This is what i did, for getting Indian currency format. if input is 1234567890 means output is 1,23,45,67,890.

Comment: does this take care of floating point values?

Comment: no it not. but we can do it like find decimal values and keep separately and then add it with end result.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en","IN")).format(number)
```

"en" is for English.
"IN" is for the country (India).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just Copy past this function. :)

```
  public static String rupeeFormat(String value){
            value=value.replace(",","");
            char lastDigit=value.charAt(value.length()-1);
            String result = "";
            int len = value.length()-1;
            int nDigits = 0;

            for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                result = value.charAt(i) + result;
                nDigits++;
                if (((nDigits % 2) == 0) && (i > 0))
                {
                    result = "," + result;
                }
            }
            return (result+lastDigit);
        }
```

Comment: Instead of doing `String` concatenation, use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I liked the way you separated the last digit and simplified the problem!

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is -

```
Double amount = 5356673553123.0; //amount is an example ,can be used with any double value

**DecimalFormat IndianCurrencyFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,##,###.00");**
```

then use it as -

```
String formattedAmount = IndianCurrencyFormat.format(amount);
```

Comment: Though I am very late to this topic, here are results of trying your code on a regular laptop with Java 8. The amount you have used gives the output as 5,356,673,553,123.00
This is still not the Indian format where every 2 digits are separated by comma except the last set of 3 digits before the decimal point.

Answer (score 4):

Please find below snippet to print currency according to locale by giving inputs

```html
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class CurrencyPayment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println("US: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(payment));
        System.out.println("India: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en","IN")).format(payment));
        System.out.println("China: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA).format(payment));
        System.out.println("France: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(payment));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no default Locale available and the user doesn't make any change to the locale, we can go with setting the currency symbol using unicode and decimal formatting. As in the below code:

For e.g. Setting the Indian currency symbol and formatting the value. This will work without user making changes in the settings.

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
    dfs.setCurrencySymbol("\u20B9");
    decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(payment));
```

Output:

```
₹12,324.13
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Android, however not sure if it works on other Java platforms.

Answer (score 2):

On Android android.icu.text.NumberFormat is available after api level 24 only. So to support lower version I wrote my own method in java.

```
public static String formatIndianCommaSeparated(long rupee){
    // remove sign if present
    String raw = String.valueOf(Math.abs(rupee));
    int numDigits = raw.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(raw);
    // Reverse the string to start from right most digits
    sb = sb.reverse();
    // Counter to keep track of number of commas placed
    int commas = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numDigits; i++){
        // Insert a comma if i is in the range [3, 5, 7, 9, ...)
        if (i % 2 == 1 && i != 1 ){
            sb.insert(i+commas, ",");
            commas++;
        }
    }
    // Reverse the string back to get original number
    String sign = (rupee < 0) ? "-" : "";
    return sign + sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin version, It works on Android API 26

```
fun currencyLocale(value: Double): String {
    val formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "in"))
    return formatter.format(value)
}

fun parseCommaSeparatedCurrency(value: String): Number {
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "in")).parse(value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few options that I explored are as below

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Locale;

    class NumberFormatDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Double d = 45124853123456.78941;
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
            System.out.println("ITALY representation of " + d + " : " + nf.format(d));

            nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
            System.out.println("GERMANY representation of " + d + " : " + nf.format(d));

            nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
            System.out.println("CHINESE representation of " + d + " : " + nf.format(d));

            nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
            System.out.println("US representation of " + d + " : " + nf.format(d));

            nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            System.out.println("ENGLISH representation of " + d + " : " + nf.format(d));

            nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);
            System.out.println("UK representation of " + d + " : " + nf.format(d));

            //===================================================
            //ICU4j example
            com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat format = com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
            System.out.println("INDIA representation of " + d + " : " + nf.format(d));
        }
    }
```

The last one reacquires following dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
<artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
<version>65.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Input:
long num = 450500;

// Unlike other countries, there is no direct Locale field for India.Therefore, we need to construct a locale for India.
Locale loc = new Locale("en", "in"); // This will display currency with "Rs." symbol.

// or use below to display currency with "INR" symbol.
Locale loc = new Locale("", "in");

NumberFormat indiacurrency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(loc);
String result = indiacurrency.format(num);
System.out.print(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String paiseToString(long paise)
{
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    boolean minus = paise < 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fmt.format(Math.abs(paise)/100.0));
    for (int index = sb.length()-6; index > 0; index-=2)
    {
        sb.insert(index,',');
    }
    if (minus)
       sb.insert(0,'-');
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String rupeesToString(long rupees)
{
    boolean minus = rupees < 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(Math.abs(rupees)));
    for (int index = sb.length()-3; index > 0; index-=2)
    {
        sb.insert(index,',');
    }
    if (minus)
       sb.insert(0,'-');
    return sb.toString();
}

// Test the functions
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Test for positive values
    long val = 1;
    while (val < Long.MAX_VALUE/10)
    {
        System.out.printf("%28s %28s\n",paiseToString(val),rupeesToString(val));
        val *= 10;
    }
    // Test for negative values
    val = -1;
    while (val > Long.MIN_VALUE/10)
    {
        System.out.printf("%28s %28s\n",paiseToString(val),rupeesToString(val));
        val *= 10;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is compact, works like a charm for Indian rupees.

Answer (score 0):

The default methods in existing libraries can only show thousands seperator. so we need to write custom function for this. You can use multiple substring operation to get the desired result.

In java,

```
function indianCurrencyNumberFormat(rupee) {
    string explore_remaining_units = "";
    if (rupee.length() > 3) {
        last_three_digits = rupee.substring((rupee.length()-3), rupee.length());
        remaining_units = rupee.substring(0, (rupee.length()-3)); 
        remaining_units =  ((remaining_units.length()) % 2 == 1) ? "0"+remaining_units : remaining_units; 
        split_rupee = remaining_units.split("(?<=^(.{2})+)")
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(split_rupee); i++) {
          explore_remaining_units += ((i == 0) ? ( (int) split_rupee[i]+"," ) : ( split_rupee[i]+"," ));  
        }
        formatted_rupee = explore_remaining_units+last_three_digits;
    } else {
        formatted_rupee = rupee;
    }
    return formatted_rupee; 
}
```

And in php:

```
function indianCurrencyNumberFormat($rupee) {
    $explore_remaining_units = "";
    if (strlen($rupee) > 3) {
        $last_three_digits = substr($rupee, strlen($rupee) - 3, strlen($rupee));
        $remaining_units = substr($rupee, 0, strlen($rupee) - 3); 
        $remaining_units = (strlen($remaining_units) % 2 == 1) ? "0".$remaining_units : $remaining_units; 
        $split_rupee = str_split($remaining_units, 2);
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($split_rupee); $i++) {
          $explore_remaining_units .= (($i == 0) ? ( (int) $split_rupee[$i] . "," ) : ( $split_rupee[$i] . "," ));  
        }
        $formatted_rupee = $explore_remaining_units.$last_three_digits;
    } else {
        $formatted_rupee = $rupee;
    }
    return $formatted_rupee; 
}
```

You can see more details [here](http://www.htmlexplorer.com/2014/05/indian-currency-or-rupee-number-format.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class string1 {

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         int i,j;
         boolean op=false;

         StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a string");
         sbuffer.append(input.nextLine());

         int length=sbuffer.length();
         if(sbuffer.length()<3)
         {
             System.out.println("string="+sbuffer);
         }
         else
         {
             for ( i = sbuffer.length(); i >0; i--) 
             {

                 if (i==length-3)
                 {
                     sbuffer.insert(i, ",");
                      op=true;
                 }
                 while(i>1 && op==true)
                 {
                     i=i-2;

                     if(i>=1)
                     {

                     sbuffer.insert(i, ",");
                     }
                 }
             }

         }
         System.out.println("string="+sbuffer);
     }
}
```

Comment: Some text explaining this code would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is better answer and works dynamically instead of specifying single Locale in code manually.

```
public String convertToDefaultCurrencyFormat(String amountToConvert){
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    String moneyString = formatter.format(Double.valueOf(amountToConvert));
    return moneyString;
}
```

for Indian rupees format change Language in your Android device:

`Setting > Language & Input Settings >` choose `English(India)`

Output:

```
₹10,00,000 (Starting with Indian Rupee symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me in Android:

```
public static String priceFormatWithDec(String price) {
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###.00");
    String format = decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(price));
    return String.format("%s", format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using Locale class and getCurrencyInstance the Indian currency format can be obtained.

while defining the new Locale for India use "en" for English and "hi" for Hindi.

for locale refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html

for getCurrencyInstance refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance--

here is a small implementation of the same.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
    scanner.close();

    Locale indialocale=new Locale("en","IN");
    NumberFormat india  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(indialocale);
    System.out.println("India: " + india.format(payment));
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me ..

```
public String indianCurrencyFormat(String s) {

    String orignalNo = s;
    String formatted = "";

    if(orignalNo.startsWith("-")) {
        s = s.replace("-","");
    }

    if(orignalNo.contains(".")) {
        if(s.length() > 6){
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s);
            s = sb.reverse().toString();

            formatted = s.substring(0,6);
            s = s.substring(6);

            while(s.length() > 1) {
                formatted += "," + s.substring(0,2);
                s = s.substring(2);
            }

            sb = new StringBuilder(formatted+(StringUtils.isNotBlank(s) ? ","+s :""));
            formatted = sb.reverse().toString();
        } else {
            formatted = s;
        }
    } else {
        if(s.length() > 3){
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s);
            s = sb.reverse().toString();

            formatted = s.substring(0,3);
            s = s.substring(3);

            while(s.length() > 1) {
                formatted += "," + s.substring(0,2);
                s = s.substring(2);
            }

            sb = new StringBuilder(formatted+(StringUtils.isNotBlank(s) ? ","+s :""));
            formatted = sb.reverse().toString();
        } else {
            formatted = s;
        }
    }

    if (orignalNo.startsWith("-")){
        formatted = "-"+formatted;
    }

    return formatted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
fun getFormattedPrice(price: Double?): String {
        if (price == null) return "0"
        val formatter = DecimalFormat("##,##,###.00").format(price)
        var formattedPrice = formatter.format(price)
        if (formattedPrice.endsWith(".00")) formattedPrice = formattedPrice.dropLast(3)
        if (formattedPrice.isEmpty()) formattedPrice = "0"
        return formattedPrice
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double number = 100000.00

NumberFormat numberFormat = new NumberFormat();

Locale locale = new Locale("hi","IN");

numberFormat = Numberformat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

double yourFormattedNumber = numberFormat(number);

OutPut = ₹1,00,000.00

//Remove "₹" using String.replace()

String myFormattedNumber = numberFormat.format(number).replace("₹","");
```

OutPut = 1,00,000.00
[image: Enjoy!! Happy coding]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar question in an interview and I used the below code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class AssignmentFour {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        int length = sb.length();
        if (length > 4) {
            for (int i = length - 3; i > 0; i -= 2) {
                sb.insert(i, ",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String addCommaToCurrency(String value) {
    // 100
   if(value.length()>3) {
       String[] arr = value.split("\\.");
       System.out.println(arr[0]);
       //0987654321
       
       boolean addCommaAfterThree = true;
       
       StringBuilder reverseValue = new StringBuilder(arr[0]).reverse();
       String commaAddedValue = "";
       int counter = 0;
       System.out.println("reverseValue length: "+reverseValue.length());
       
       for(int i=0; i<reverseValue.length(); i++) {
           if(addCommaAfterThree && counter == 3) {
               commaAddedValue = commaAddedValue+","+reverseValue.charAt(i); //098,7
               counter = 1;
               addCommaAfterThree = false;
           } else if(counter == 2 && !addCommaAfterThree) {
               commaAddedValue = commaAddedValue+","+reverseValue.charAt(i); //098,7
               counter = 1;
           } else {
               commaAddedValue = commaAddedValue+reverseValue.charAt(i) +""; 
               counter = counter +1;
           }
       }
       
       System.out.println("Comma Added value "+new StringBuilder(commaAddedValue).reverse().append("."+arr[1]));
       return new StringBuilder(commaAddedValue).reverse().append("."+arr[1]).toString();
   }
   return value;}
```

Kindly use this method it working it was my project requirement

Answer (score 0):

import com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

// use 'en_IN' as language in Locale. This will give you desired output without "Rs" before number

Locale indianLocale = new Locale("en_IN", "IN");
NumberFormat indianFormat1 = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(indianLocale);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
 fun currencyFormatter(inputNumbers: String?): String {
        var formattedNumber = ""
        var decimalPoint=""
        var inputNumber=""

        if (inputNumbers != null) {
            try {
                val sp=inputNumbers.split(".")
                inputNumber=sp[0]
                decimalPoint=sp[1]
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                inputNumber=inputNumbers
            }


            formattedNumber = when {
                inputNumber.length <= 3 -> {
                    inputNumber
                }
                inputNumber.length <= 5 -> {
                    String.format("%s,%s", inputNumber.substring(0, inputNumber.length - 3),
                        inputNumber.substring(inputNumber.length - 3))
                }
                inputNumber.length <= 7 -> {
                    String.format("%s,%s,%s",
                        inputNumber.substring(0, inputNumber.length - 5),
                        inputNumber.substring(inputNumber.length - 5, inputNumber.length - 3),
                        inputNumber.substring(inputNumber.length - 3)
                    )
                }
                inputNumber.length <= 9 -> {
                    String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s",
                        inputNumber.substring(0, inputNumber.length - 7),
                        inputNumber.substring(inputNumber.length - 7, inputNumber.length - 5),
                        inputNumber.substring(inputNumber.length - 5, inputNumber.length - 3),
                        inputNumber.substring(inputNumber.length - 3)
                    )
                }
                else -> inputNumber
            }
        }
        return "$formattedNumber.$decimalPoint"
    }

main(){
 val rs=1200.55f
    print(currencyFormatter(rs.toString()))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Converting any Number into Indian Rupee Format in Golang.
2. Function IndianRupeeFormat takes paramter as string and returns as string

   ```golang
   func IndianRupeeFormat(DisplayAmount string) string {
       AmountDisplayed := DisplayAmount[:len(DisplayAmount)-3] // just removing decimal point numbers.
       IndianRupee := ""
       if len(AmountDisplayed) > 3 { // amount should to greater than 999 if "," should appear , so length should be greater than 3
           startIndex := math.Mod(float64(len(AmountDisplayed)), 2) // startIndex is taken as slicing part to add comma.
           noOfCommas := (len(AmountDisplayed) / 2) - 1             // No of Commas appear in the number.
           startSlice := 0                                          // start of the slice
           for i := 0; i < noOfCommas; i++ {
               IndianRupee = IndianRupee + DisplayAmount[startSlice:int64(startIndex)+1] + ","
               startIndex = startIndex + 2 // adding +2 because after first comma we are skipping 2 digits to add another comma.
               startSlice = int(startIndex) - 1
           }
           k := len(DisplayAmount) - 6
           IndianRupee = IndianRupee + DisplayAmount[k:] // adding the rest of digits.
       } else {
           IndianRupee = DisplayAmount
       }
       return IndianRupee
   }

   Amount1 := IndianRupeeFormat(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f",100))
   Amount2 := IndianRupeeFormat(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f",1000.345))
   Amount3 := IndianRupeeFormat(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f",10000.02))
   Amount4 := IndianRupeeFormat(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f",100000.100))
   Amount5 := IndianRupeeFormat(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f",1000000.))
   Amount6 := IndianRupeeFormat(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f",1000.090))
   fmt.Println(Amount1)
   fmt.Println(Amount2)
   fmt.Println(Amount3)
   fmt.Println(Amount4)
   fmt.Println(Amount5)
   fmt.Println(Amount6)
   // Output: 100
   // Output: 1,000.34
   // Output: 10,000.02
   // Output: 1,00,000.10
   // Output: 10,00,000.00
   // Output: 1,000.90
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question but I'll add my answer just in case. It is possible to use the same decimal formatter in a roundabout way to achieve the result but it isn't the most efficient solution, just a simpler one.

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class IndianMoneyFormat {

    static String indianCurrencyFormat(double money) {
        String result = null;

        double aboveThousands = money / 1000;
        double thousands = money % 1000;

        if (aboveThousands > 1) {
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##,##");
            formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN); //will round towards zero whether negative or positive. Same as truncating.
            String one = formatter.format(aboveThousands);

            formatter.applyPattern("###.00");
            formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); //default rounding mode of DecimalFormat
            String two = formatter.format(thousands);

            result = one + "," + two;
            return result;
        } else {
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.00");
            result = formatter.format(money);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double money1 = 123000999.5;
        double money2 = 999.39;
        System.out.println(indianCurrencyFormat(money1));
        System.out.println(indianCurrencyFormat(money2));
    }
}
```

Above code will provide the following result:

```
12,30,00,999.50
999.39
```

Answer (score -4):

> ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_CurrencyFormat](@UC varchar(50)) RETURNS
>   varchar(50) AS BEGIN declare @FC varchar(50),@Scale varchar(3),@i
>   bigint=1,@a int=3,@b int=2,@WhileLength bigint,@UCScale varchar(50),
>   @Con varchar(20) set @Scale=charindex('.',@UC) --if number has '.'
>   then value else '0' if(@Scale!='0') begin set @UCScale=@UC set
>   @Con=substring(@UCScale,charindex('.',@UCScale),3) set
>   @UC=substring(@UC,0,charindex('.',@UC)) -- substring end
>   if(cast(len(@UC) as bigint)%2!=0) --if odd begin set
>   @WhileLength=(cast(len(@UC) as bigint)-3)/2 while(@i<=@WhileLength) --
>   length-3/2=3 if length is 9 (cast(len(@UC) as bigint)-3)/2 begin set
>   @a=3*@i set @UC = stuff(@UC,@a,0,',') set @i=@i+1 end --while set
>   @FC=@UC end --if odd Scale '0' else if(cast(len(@UC) as bigint)%2=0)
>   --if even begin set @WhileLength=(((cast(len(@UC) as bigint)-1)-3)/2)+1 while(@i<=@WhileLength) begin if(@i=1) begin set
>   @UC=stuff(@UC,@b,0,',') end else begin set @b=@b+3 set
>   @UC=stuff(@UC,@b,0,',') end set @i=@i+1 end set @FC=@UC end
>   if(@Scale!='0') begin set @FC=@FC+@Con end --if(@Scale!='0') --set
>   @FC=@UC return @FC END

Comment: This TSQL function formats yours currency value with required commas, like 1000 to 1,000 or 10000 to 10,000. You just need to call copy-paste & execute the function and call like this :  select dbo.udf_CurrencyFormat(123456)