# Converting number to comma separated format in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format)

I have input number "123456" and want to convert it to "1,23,456" format in Java?

1234--> 1,234
 and vice versa.

Any string operations present in Java library?

Answer (score 5):

try java.text.NumberFormat for number formatting