# How I put character , between numbers?

Tags: java, android

I want to put (,) between per 3 numbers from right in large numbers Decimal.
How I do it?

for exp = 12345678 to 12,345,678

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting number to comma separated format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703790/converting-number-to-comma-separated-format-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `NumberFormat` for format your number. Do not add commas in manually:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int num = 12345678;
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    System.out.println(format.format(num));
}
```

Output:

```
12,345,678
```

You can also use the `static` method `format` on the `String` class to achieve the same goal:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%,d", num));
```

As others have pointed out this is all assuming that your default `Locale` is one where commas are used as grouping separators and not dots. You can add a `Locale` into both methods to force the issue:

```
final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Locale.UK);
```

and

```
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.UK, "%,d", num));
```

The `String.format` method actually takes a [format `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) which is fairly powerful in what you can tell it to do. The `NumberFormat` is more specialised for formatting only numbers.

Comment: You should note that the output depends on the locale. It could also be `12.345.678`

Comment: You should precise a Locale where it separates with a `','` like `final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Locale.US);`

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
 public static String convert(String number){
        String convert=String.format("%,d", Integer.parseInt(number));
       return convert;
    }
```