# Indian Currency Validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please can anyone respond to this... its very urgent..

the function should validate the below 1.23,0.05.0.3,0.00,89.45632 and should not accept 0.,00123,045,.,89.,563245.,12..3,12...,hjhj,gh.23,h.   there can be atleast one decimal point

Thanks in Advance
Radhika

Comment: maybe you should better describe what is a valid format, using just a few example is not always sufficient to behave correctly in the border cases

Comment: I assume `0.05.0.3` is a typo as a valid format?

Comment: Surprisingly hard to find. Perhaps http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2699

Comment: "it is very urgent" is considered [very rude](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent). Also: if you want good answers, format your question to be readable: your examples are hardly readable.

Comment: I agree they are not understandable. Something like this works better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that returns true if it is given a decimal number or a string representing a decimal number, and false otherwise.

I hope that is what you wanted.

```
function validate(s){
    return /\d+(.\d+)/.test(s)&&!/^0\d+/.test(s);
}
```

If you want the function also accepts natural numbers like "2", "0", or "10" then use this instead:

```
function validate(s){
    return /\d+(\.\d+)?/.test(s)&&!/^0\d+/.test(s);
}
```