# How to display Indian Numbering format in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReports to generate Reports. I want to display the GrandTotal fields in Indian Numbering Format. 
For Example,

```
Value: 1,000,000 should be displayed as 10,00,000
```

I tried using Pattern of text field properties, but not able to get the result. 
And in some forums they have mentioned to use JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE. I tried this way

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "IN");
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);
```

where parameters is a map which is then used to fill report.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use 
[ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/) you can do something like

`com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in")).format(new Java.math.BigDecimal(${FIELD_HOLDING_THE_VALUE}));`

NumberFormat of ICU4J is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379337/1767366) thread

Comment: how to include this in iReports ? Please guide

Comment: You need to add the icu4j jar into the iReport class path as well where ever the report is deployed to.

Comment: ok, is there a way to generalize this, I want it to get applied to all my reports, by using some JRParameter ?

Comment: Since you're already passing your desired locale to REPORT_LOCALE parameter inside the report, you can just replace the part `new Locale("en", "in")` in my answer with `$P{REPORT_LOCALE}`