# Java i18N Where to put grouping separator in a DecimalFormat pattern for Asian Locales

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, number-formatting

For Indian Locale grouping separator placement varies i.e. it's not fixed to appear after every 3 digits
e.g
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000

I want to construct a DecimalFormat Pattern for above locale such that grouping seperators are also shown at correct places

If i specify grouping seperator in a pattern then grouping separator placement gets fixed

Patterns that i tried

```
##,###  -> grouping seperator is fixed to appear after every 3 digits
##,##   -> grouping seperator is fixed to appear after every 2 digits
##      -> does not show grouping seperator
```

**Reason: Why i want to acheive this via DecimalFormat Pattern**
I am using Spring MVC and wants to leverage its  `@NumberFormat` annotation to do number formatting on my Model Fields
In this annotation,i can only specify decimal format pattern.

I am hoping this could be achieved by specifying correct decimal format pattern and i don't have to create my own Number formatter.

Comment: I don't know if this can be used with the Spring `@NumberFormat` annotation, but the ICU project supports an India-aware number format. Look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format

Comment: You don't mess with the pattern, you set the proper locale.