# Number Format (Comma Separation) as per locale

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have a requirement to show a number value like `123456789.905` in the following format `123,456,789.90`. But the comma separation changes depending on the locale selected in the phone (as if with US English selected comma separation is 3 places and if India English is selected it is like `12,34,56,789.90`).

How can I format my `Double`?

Comment: It may be helpful if you post your current code so we know what you've tried.

Comment: Do you want the number to be formatted the same way in any language? I mean... should it be `123,456,789.90` regardless of the current locale?

Comment: @RenéLink no, he said: "if India English is selected".

Answer (score 3):

So, `java.text.NumberFormat` doesn't slove the problem, unfortunately, but [`com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/NumberFormat.html) does.

You can use this:

```
Double d = 123456789.905;
com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat format = com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

System.out.println(format.format(d));
```

This outputs: `12,34,56,789.90`.

Answer (score 2):

For the generic case, use [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
String formatted = nf.format(yourDoubleValue);
```

By default `getInstance()` returns a `NumberFormat` that is configured as appropriate for the current `Locale`. You can change the configuration yourself, too.

The "comma separation" is called "grouping".

For the specific case of grouping in an Indian currency format, see: [Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
try {
                    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(l);
                    String formato = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(your_data);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), which helps you to format and parse numbers for any locale.

> Your code can be completely independent of the locale conventions for
>   decimal points, thousands-separators, or even the particular decimal
>   digits used, or whether the number format is even decimal.

```
Locale fmtLocale = Locale.getDefault();
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(fmtLocale);
formatter.format(your_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I have not found for any locale in `NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()` a format with only two digits between grouping signs (for example for `new Locale("en", "IN")`). So I think you have to use DecimalFormat-pattern like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##,##,##,##,##.###");
System.out.println(df.format(123456789.905));
// Output: 1.23.45.67.89,905
```

It is not exactly the same since DecimalFormat is not able to have varying counts of grouping sizes, but maybe this is acceptable for you.

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

double value = nf.parse(iValue).doubleValue();