# How to convert string ( that contains comma separated values.) to an Integer

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a String to an Integer value.

```
example : "3,879" to 3879.
```

How to do that using `java.text.Numberformat;` or If there is any other way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will get it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883402/number-format-comma-separation-as-per-locale

Comment: Are you wanting to keep the comma?

Comment: No, I don`t want to keep comma. I want to convert comma separated values to Integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
String myNumber = "3,359";
myNumber = myNumber.replaceAll(",", "");
int test = Integer.parseInt(myNumber);
System.out.println("" + test);
```

You can do it like this also:

[link for number formatpackage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973442/4028085)

This answer uses code from above link:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse("265,858");

int test = 0;
try {
    test = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse("265,858").intValue();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("" + test);
```

Comment: Being picky, but the sop doesn't require `"" + ` to print integer variables.

Comment: :), I have solved problem with replaceAll(), but I want it to be solved with Numberformat pacakge - Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can strip the commas with replaceAll from the string and use parseInt.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt( yourstr.replaceAll("[^0-9]",""));
```