# DecimalFormat with different number of grouping

Tags: java, format

I want to group a decimal with different number of grouping by `,` . But it takes the last grouping only and applies for all grouping. How to format this as expected.

```
String rupeePattern = "###,##,##,###.##";
double price = 210234.505; //to be formatted to 2,10,234.51
System.out.println("Price:"+ customFormat(rupeePattern, price)); // but get 210,234.51


public static String customFormat(String pattern, double value) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    return formatter.format(value);
}
```

Comment: what is ur locale(default)?

Comment: Looks like this is not supported, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5379337/3344829

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder en_IN

Comment: @Saravana that link has an answer that works.