# Conversion of Crores into rupees in java

Tags: java, excel, numbers, number-formatting

I have a value is like this

- 3.78 (crores) should be displayed as: 3,78,00,000
- 16.386(crores) should be displayed as: 16,38,60,000
- 465.12(crores) should be displayed as: 4,65,12,00,000

Comment: Are you using a `,` every two or three digits?  What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? Are you using Java or excel?

Comment: Only guessing: are you talking about formatting of floating-point numbers?

Comment: Simply multiply the value with 100,000

Comment: For formatting, see [Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5379231/1288408). Might be a duplicate, not sure.

Comment: @PeterLawrey and other non-Indian readers, the currency has thousand separators with groups of 2-2-...-2-3 digits. Tja.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you. That is mad, I though `,` was being used as a decimal somehow.