# Using string format to add dollar sign and commas to my numbers

Tags: java, formatting

I'm relatively new to Java, and I have a line of code I'm struggling with:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-14s%10.2f","Income",income));
```

I would like to add a $ and commas to the income, but whenever I try to add it in the line, I get errors or the $ shows up in the wrong spot.

So currently it prints:

```
Income      50000.00
```

but I would like it to print:

```
Income     $50,000.00
```

If there is a way to add these additions while keeping 'Income' and the digits nicely spaced apart, that'd be preferred. :)

Comment: can you provide sample input and desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with `String.format` only:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-14s$%,.2f","Income",50000.));
```

it will print `Income        $50,000.00`

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to display $ amount in US number format than try:

```
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###.##");
System.out.println("$" + dFormat.format(income));
```

Comment: Better yet: `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)`

Comment: When I tried to use the code, I keep getting the error "cannot find symbol"

Answer (score 1):

You should use `decimal format` and format the number.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(100000);
System.out.println("$" + yourFormattedString);
```

The result will be

```
-> 1,000,000 for 1000000         
-> 10,000 for 10000         
-> 1,000 for 1000
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? The answer here is no different from the one above

Comment: Question *specifically* asked for formatting with $ sign, and this answer doesn't do that.

Comment: @Andreas Seems to me that the line `System.out.println("$" + yourFormattedString);` DOES use the dollar sign.

Comment: @FredK You mean the `print` statement that was added to the answer *after* I left the comment? --- Also note that I'm not the downvoter, just my take on why a downvote could have been given.

Comment: Better yet: `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)`