# Android- TextView Set decimal value incorrectly printing comma

Tags: java, android, decimal

For localising my app I am using strings.xml for three languages

I have a statement

current balance: Rs. %0.2f

I populate this at runtime by using

getResources().getString(R.string.home_survey_text, user.demographicsPrice)

this seems to be working for English and Hindi where I get value as

current balance: Rs. 1.45

but for Kannada I am gettting

current balance: Rs. 1,45.

the comma is incorrectly being displayed. Need help with the same, stackoverflow reading recommendation anything that would help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "comma is incorrectly displayed" ? What is incorrect ? what did you expect ?

Comment: Localization is a pain in Android or any application for that matter. You'd need to use the NumberFormat or code a special case, linked here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator . The comma delimiter is used instead of the dot delimiter in several languages. It appears Android doesn't have one correctly set for Kannada.

You might want to read these too;

Indian Number System: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format

Currency Symbol for Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing values-kn_IN to values-kn in folder structure did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can user a formatter to format your number however you choose.

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
String number = formatter.format(1/3);
```

*number will be 0.3*

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,#");
String number = formatter.format(1/3);
```

*number will be 0,3*