# Display Indian Currency in Thymeleaf + Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to display the Indian currency format using SpringBoot + Thymeleaf.
I have used the following code in HTML to display it

```
<td th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(revenueDetailsDto.getTotalCommissionablePremium())}"></td>

  @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "IN"));
        return slr;
    }
```

This is showing strings as-
Rs.1,599,176.00 .

However, I want results in Indian Numeric format like-
Rs. 15,99,176.00 .

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: This seems to be a bug. What if you do a test and print the currency with Plain Java like described here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/numberformat.html

Comment: I tried with the below code, but the same issue   NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
  System.out.println(numberFormat.format(73746842.00));

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Java NumberFomat does not support this India currency format.

See: [Displaying Currency in Indian Numbering Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format)

You will need to format the on the server side already.