# How to implement indian comma system in the rupees from tibco software

Tags: java, spring-boot, report, tibco

Right now I'm using [these codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbacl.jpg) to add the pattern but still I'm having the rupee format as `111,111,111` and I want it to be `11,11,111`.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please post your code as text here.

Comment: Not sure this is best solution but this link may be useful . https://stackoverflow.com/a/31448792/4581618