How to add INR currency Format with decimal places with max length 8 Digit and 2 decimal value
developers I'm developing Amount to Words convert with INR currency format with max length 8 and 2 decimal values I've achieved this in USA currency format but when I tried with INR it's not accepting decimal values I need your help to accomplish this.
fun setAmountFilter(editText: EditText) {

    editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
    editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(16))

    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            try {
                val text = s?.toString() ?: ""
                val cursorPosition = editText.selectionStart
                val formattedText = formatAmountText(text)
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
                println("formattedText: $formattedText")
                editText.setText(formattedText)

                editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
                // Calculate the adjusted cursor positioned based on the formatting
                val adjustCursorPosition =
                    getAdjustCursorPosition(text, cursorPosition, formattedText)
                // set cursor position back to its adjusted position or the end if it exceeds the new text length
                editText.setSelection(min(adjustCursorPosition, formattedText.length))
            } catch (_: Exception) {

            }


        }
    })

}

Amount format with max and 2 decimal value
fun formatAmountText(input: String): String {
    val maxLength = 8
    val maxDecimalPlaces = 2

    //Remove all non-numeric characters except the decimal point
    val numericOnly = input.replace(Regex("[^0-9.]"), "")

    // check if the input contains a decimal point
    val containsDecimalPoint = numericOnly.contains(".")

    // Split the number into integer and decimal parts
    val parts = numericOnly.split(".")
    val integerPart = parts.getOrNull(0) ?: ""
    val decimalPart = parts.getOrNull(1) ?: ""

    // Truncate the integer part if it exceeds the maximum length
    val truncatedIntegerPart = if (integerPart.length > maxLength) {
        integerPart.substring(0, maxLength)
    } else {
        integerPart
    }

    //Limit the decimal part to the maximum decimal places of it exits

    val truncatedDecimalPart =
        if (decimalPart.isNotEmpty() && decimalPart.length > maxDecimalPlaces) {
            decimalPart.substring(0, maxDecimalPlaces)
        } else {
            decimalPart
        }

    // Combine the integer and decimal parts
    val combinedParts = when {
        truncatedDecimalPart.isNotEmpty() -> "$truncatedIntegerPart.$truncatedDecimalPart"
        containsDecimalPoint -> "$truncatedIntegerPart."
        else -> truncatedIntegerPart
    }
   // return formatCurrency(combinedParts.toDouble())
    return addCommaToNumber(combinedParts)

}

this function is used but not converted to INR format
  private fun addCommaToNumber(input: String): String {
    val numberPattern = "(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))"
    return input.replace(numberPattern.toRegex(), "$1,")
}

Then I found one solution that works perfectly for INR currency format but it's not accepting the decimal dot (.) but gives the output as expected.
fun addCommaToCurrency(input: String): String {
// Split the input into integer and decimal parts
val parts = input.split("\\.".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
val integerPart = parts[0]
val decimalPart = if (parts.size > 1) parts[1] else ""

val reverseValue = StringBuilder(integerPart).reverse()
val commaAddedValue = StringBuilder()
var counter = 0

for (i in 0 until reverseValue.length) {
    if (i > 3 && (i - 3) % 2 == 0) {
        commaAddedValue.append(',')
    } else if (i == 3) {
        commaAddedValue.append(',')
    }
    commaAddedValue.append(reverseValue[i])
}

val formattedIntegerPart = commaAddedValue.reverse().toString()
return if (decimalPart.isNotEmpty()) {
    "$formattedIntegerPart.$decimalPart"
} else {
    formattedIntegerPart
}

}
And I've used one function when any digit is removed from any position the cursor will be at same position and it will not move to last position here is the code
private fun getAdjustCursorPosition(
    originalText: String,
    originalCursorPosition: Int,
    formattedText: String
): Int {

    var commasInOriginalText = 0
    var commasInFormattedTexts = 0

    for (i in 0 until originalCursorPosition) {
        if (originalText[i] == ',') {
            commasInOriginalText++
        }
    }

    for (i in 0 until min(originalCursorPosition, formattedText.length)) {
        if (formattedText[i] == ',')
            commasInFormattedTexts++
    }

    val adjustedCursorPosition =
        originalCursorPosition + commasInFormattedTexts - commasInOriginalText
    return adjustedCursorPosition
}

Please help me to solve this problem
I need out put as
12.22
100.22
100
13,500
14,767.22
1,00,000
1,00,767.43 goes on till max length 8 and 2 decimal value.

You might be trying to reinvent the wheel. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379337/13963086

I've modified the addCommaToNumber function and it works as per expected.
private fun addCommaToNumber(input: String): String {
val numberPattern = "(\\B(?=(?:(\\d\\d)+(\\d)(?!\\d))+(?!\\d)))"
return input.replace(numberPattern.toRegex(), "$1,")

}
