# How to verify currency in Java?

Tags: java, string, currency

If I get a `String` value like

> $10

what is the best and concise way of to verify the currency value?

Currently I am using Usual `String` Methods like `startsWith("$")` and get the rest and change them to `Double` value if they are numeric.

Comment: What do you mean by "verify the currency value"?

Comment: do you have pre-defined format? how about RegEx?

Comment: basically I need to check if the string is a currency or not if yes I need to extract the numeric value for other purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Regular Expression to match dollar amounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864213/java-regular-expression-to-match-dollar-amounts)

Comment: it must start with $

Comment: By the way, [you shouldn't use floating point data types for currency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/4125191).

Comment: And how do you know whether $ is US or Canada? There is a [`Currency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) class in java (and/or preferably [Joda-Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/)). But apart from those, you'll need to do the splitting part manually based on your requirements.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544454/get-the-currency-format-for-a-country-that-does-not-have-a-locale-constant